# React native Webview error, App not installing Help me to solve this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-webview, jsx

I am creating an app that uses webview. I installed and imported the webview and when using it, app was not installed in the android emulator. Without webview app installing correctly.
I tried by creating another project for example ,same error returns.

Here is the error by using webview:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'F:\FirstProject\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\build.gradle' line: 35

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-webview'.
> org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/PropertiesKt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-webview'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
```

I am using java version: java 15.0.2
compileSdkVersion : 30

Comment: 'compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle'

Did you check your build.gradle files? 

One is in yourProject/android and one in yourProject/android/app

Comment: the error show in `react-native-webview\android\build.gradle' line: 35`   .and code in that file is                        
**apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'**  line 35

Comment: @XplosiVe06 I have checked the gradle and all the files are declared.